# How do I find duplicates in XML if an element contains value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XML:

```
<root>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<p>This is a Value</p>
<h3>Another Value</h3>
<h3>Another Value</h3>
<h3>Another Value</h3>
<h3>Another Value</h3>
<h3>This is Another Value</h3>
</root>
```

I want to find duplicate values. So, I did this:

```
var valueDuplicate = xdoc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "p" || n.Name.LocalName == "pw" ||
                                                       n.Name.LocalName == "plt" || n.Name.LocalName == "psf")
                             .GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                             .Select(g => new { ElementValue = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
string s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, valueDuplicate.Select(t => "Value: " + t.ElementValue.Trim() + "- "
                                                                                        + t.Count + " times."));
```

This finds the duplicate values, but it does not show `<h3>This is Another Value</h3>` as a duplicate. I want to find all elements that contain the value as well.

Comment: Use `g.Count() >= 1` ?

Comment: This searches almost everything in the file. I want to search for only the distinct values in `valueDuplicate`.

Comment: Do you need **Group By** with contains?

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour - Yes. So, all elements `Equals()` or `Contains()` **Value** or **Another Value**, it will be shown. My code just deals with `Equals()`

Comment: Your output must be : **Value: Value- 11 times.**  ?

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour - Yes. You are right. I will edit the question as this input might be confusing.

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour - I have edited the question so not the output will be **Value: This is a Value- 6 times** and **Value: Another Value- 5 times**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var values = xdoc.Descendants().Select(x => x.Value);
var valueDuplicate = xdoc.Descendants().Select(r => new
 {
  el = r,
  value = values.FirstOrDefault(c => r.Value.Contains(c) || r.Value == c)
 }).GroupBy(x => x.value, x => x.el).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();

string s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, valueDuplicate.Select(t => "Value: " + t.Key.Trim() + "- " + t.Count() + " times."));
```

Comment: This works :). Just an update, it also takes null values in the `valueDuplicate` variable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument XDocument = XDocument.Parse(MyXmlFile);
        var grouped = XDocument.Descendants("P").GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        foreach (var groupItem in grouped)
        {
            foreach (var item in groupItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems like this will have the same output as mine. It does not deal with `Contains()`, only `Equals()`.

Comment: var xml_Doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("xmlpath.xml"));

        IEnumerable<XElement> search_date = null;
        search_date =
            (from xFi in xml_Doc.Descendants("List")
                where xFi.Element("tag").Value.Contains("value")
                select xFi
            );